# Create workitem in Azure Devops from Postman

Tags: azure-devops, postman, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

We are looking to move from Jira to Azure Devops with all of our projects, one of those being our helpdesk functionality.

I have been tasked with porting our current solution regarding tickets: We have a Laravel project running that checks certain email addresses for new help requests. When a new email arrives it sends a notification to our Slack where one of the team members acknowledge it and chooses where to create a ticket in Jira. Then it creates a new ticket in Jira with an api-call, based on the choice in Slack.

I have found and tried out the Azure Devops API, and can list projects and get workitems and so on. But I cannot POST a new workitem by calling

```
http://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=6.1-preview.3&bypassRules=true
```

with a JSON body like this:

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "from": null,
        "value": "Test of REST functionality"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.State",
        "from": null,
        "value": "New"
    }
]
```

I get a JSON response like this

```
{
    "fields": {
        "System.WorkItemType": "Task",
        "System.AreaPath": "xxxxx",
        "System.TeamProject": "xxxx",
        "System.IterationPath": "xxxx",
        "System.State": "New",
        "System.Reason": "New",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate": "1753-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "System.ChangedBy": {
            "displayName": "xxxx",
            "url": "xxxx",
            "_links": {
                "avatar": {
                    "href": "xxxx"
                }
            },
            "id": "xxxx",
            "uniqueName": "xxxx",
            "imageUrl": "xxxx",
            "descriptor": "xxxx"
        },
        "System.CreatedBy": {
            "displayName": "xxxx",
            "url": "xxxx",
            "_links": {
                "avatar": {
                    "href": "xxxx"
                }
            },
            "id": "xxxx",
            "uniqueName": "xxxx",
            "imageUrl": "xxxx",
            "descriptor": "xxxx"
        },
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority": 2
    },
    "_links": {
        "workItemType": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItemTypes/Task"
        },
        "fields": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/fields"
        }
    },
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems"
}
```

That last url refers me to a page with a JSON object containing this message:

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://dev.azure.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems'
```

and no new tasks are created.

I started with consulting the documentation.

I have tried editing and regenerating my Personal Access Token with several different combinations of permissions regarding work items. I have tried giving the PAT full access.

I have tried calling different versions of the API.

I have tried adding fields besides title and state that are listed as required, ending with setting bypassRules to true.

Google and the /r/azuredevops subreddit returned no results that worked.

Can anyone point me in the direction of where I should go, or what I'm missing?
Thanks in advance :-)

EDIT: I am POSTing.

[image: POST]

***EDIT FOR SOLUTION:***

I feel so stupid. When POSTing in Postman, I used http:// instead of https://
Using https:// solved the issue.

Comment: Hi, According to the response body, it seems that your postman method is GET instead of POST, you could check my answer and then kindly share the result here.

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I added a little extra info - It mostly does, but I'd like to know what you have in your url and what you have in headers. You have 12 headers and I have 9, and my url seems longer than yours.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer, it contains my URL and detail steps with header, you could check it and kindly share the result here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the pic, according to the request body, it seems that your are using the REST API [get work item type definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) instead of [Create Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

If the method is **GET**, it will get the work item type.

Request Body:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemtypes/{type}?api-version=6.0
```

the JSON response like this:

```
    {
            "fields": {
                  .....
                },
            "_links": {
                  .....                    
                },
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems"
        }
```

Postman Result:

[image]

If we need create work item, we need change the method to **POST**

Request URL:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=6.0
```

Request Body:

```
[
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.Title",
        "from": null,
        "value": "Test of REST functionality"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "path": "/fields/System.State",
        "from": null,
        "value": "New"
    }
]
```

the JSON response like this:

```
{
    "id": {Work Item ID},
    "rev": 1,
    "fields": {
      ...
    },
    "_links": {
      ...
    },
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{Work Item ID}"
}
```

Postman Result:

[image]

And Azure DevOps Service result:

[image]

**Update1**

> but I'd like to know what you have in your url

My URL is

```
https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/wit/workitems/$task?api-version=6.0
```

> You have 12 headers and I have 9, and my url seems longer than yours

1. Create a new request page in the postman, the default Header is 7, enter Request URL, it will add the header `Cookie` and now the Header is 8.

[image]

2. Change the method from GET to POST, it will add the header `Content-Length` and now the Header is 9.

[image]

3. Click the **Body** tab->select **raw** and change the content type to **JSON** to add Request Body, it will add the header `Content-Type` and now the Header is 10

[image]

4. Click the **Authorization** tab->select **Basic Auth** and enter the PAT Token as password, it will add the header `Authorization` and now the Header is 11.

[image]

5. Now, when we click the Send button, we will get the error message `The request indicated a Content-Type of \"application/json\" for method type \"POST\" which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are: application/json-patch+json.`

[image]

6. Click the Header tab, the default value of `Content-Type` is `application/json`, we need to disable it and add new header `Content-Type` and set the value to  `application/json-patch+json`, and now the Header is 12

[image]

7. Click the button Send and response code is 200

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I followed your guide to the T, ended up with the exact same result. I have tagged your answer as correct, because it's a great guide

Comment: I solved it. Or, a colleague of mine told me that a POST request loses its body when it gets redirected from http to https. So when I used https, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your are attempting to create more than one task, which is not supported by this endpoint according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) 
[image].

I managed to create a task with the following body:

```json
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]
```

Headers included:

- Content-Type : application/json-patch+json
- Authentication : Basic encoded-PAT

The content type header is mentioned in the Body Request section in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#request-body).

For the PAT Token, you only need **vso.work_write**, also mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#security).

The endpoint Url is: `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=6.0`

The response body looks like this

```json
{
    "id": 8921,
    "rev": 1,
    "fields": {
        "System.AreaPath": "Project",
        "System.TeamProject": "Project",
        "System.IterationPath": "Project",
        "System.WorkItemType": "Task",
        "System.State": "New",
        "System.Reason": "New",
        "System.CreatedDate": "2021-03-17T10:36:25.513Z",
        "System.CreatedBy": ....,
        "System.ChangedDate": "2021-03-17T10:36:25.513Z",
        "System.ChangedBy": ....,
        "System.CommentCount": 0,
        "System.Title": "Sample task",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate": "2021-03-17T10:36:25.513Z",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority": 2
    },
    "_links": { some links
    },
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/Organization/14360bf9-7578-4sfs-b43f-8dfda139fb17/_apis/wit/workItems/8921"
}
```

The final attribute `url` includes the correct link to the newly created WorkItem.

Comment: I edited my OP with an image - I am POSTing, but I can see you have a much shorter url than me, particularly around the {organization}/{project} part, and you have more in headers than me. The official documentation says both org and project should be in the url, but your screenshots makes me wonder if you have something else in headers and url than I have. - 

Official docs;     POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=6.1-preview.3     -     
And I have 9 headers, while you have 12?